# Fail to extract rar archive

Tags: 20.04, files, archive, zip, rar

I have a `.rar` archive. I can open it using `Archive Manager`. Files are ready to view individually. But it cant extract all of the files inside the archive. The archive consists of a hierarchy of directories which contain some text files along with some video files. `Archive Manager` can only extract the text file in the last folder, neglecting all of the other files and also the video files inside the last folder. When I extract every folder separately, some of them get extracted correctly, but some others don't get extracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in terminal with `unrar`, it can help. For more info refer to [page](https://linoxide.com/how-to-extract-rar-files/).

1. Install `sudo apt-get install unrar`
2. If you want to extract all files within the '.rar' file in the
   current directory run below command (in terminal as well)

   `unrar e /path/to/file.rar`

Comment: I did it, and got disk space error. So the problem is my disk space. Thanks.